# How to make zip_longest available in itertools using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

When trying to import this function on a Python Jupyter 2.7 nb running on Windows 10, I get this error:

[image]

I believe I hadn't encountered problems in the past because I was using Python 3. So I wonder if it is just that it is not available in Python 2, or if there is a way of making it work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For Python 3, the method is `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

For Python 2, the method is `izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
```

Comment: Points for now - will accept when it allows me to (6 min). Ty

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Don't forget in Python 3, map and zip functions return iterators instead of lists, so you want to list() them if you are expecting a list.  I am constantly burned by this.  I hate it.  But lazy evaluation is king.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't know which version of python runs the script you can use this trick:

```
try:
    from itertools import zip_longest
except ImportError:
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest

# now this works in both python 2 and 3
print(list(zip_longest([1,2,3],[4,5])))
```